# What is the way to round of in TWIG?

Tags: php, twig

I need to round of numeric in my view. But there twig is used. What is the way to round of in TWIG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [format](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/format.html) filter:

{{ '%.2f' | format(10.5555) }}

But note that it will round it to 10.56.

Can also use [number_filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html)

Comment: https://github.com/falmp/Twig-extensions/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extensions/Extension/Number.php why not number_filter?

Comment: yes number_filter works too `http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html`

Comment: number_filter does not exist in my version of twig.

Comment: @user1440167 you can check answer as correct if it solves your problem so that other people can use the same.